# Trigger pipeline with jobs from another pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I need to develop two azure devops pipelines. 'Starter.yml' - is trigger for second one. 'Processing.yml' - has some business logic.

Very important thing: both of them must have jobs.

I tried doing something like this:

Starter:

```
trigger: none

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2019'

stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: Triggering
    steps:
    - template: Processing.yml
```

Processing:

```
jobs:
- job: Processing
  steps:
  - task: PowerShell@2
    inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
    # Write your PowerShell commands here.
    
    Write-Host "Hello World"
```

I get following result:

[image]

I saw a lot of examples but all of them dont work. Of course I have parallel jobs:
[image]

Is it generally possible to trigger pipeline from another pipeline when both of them have jobs?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: You cannot set 'Jobs' inside 'Jobs'. Your whole Processing.yml should be loaded as a Job. Refer here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/templates?view=azure-devops#job-reuse

Comment: jobs:
    - template: Processing.yml

Comment: About "'Starter.yml' - is trigger for second one.", do you mean 'Processing.yml' should be triggered by 'Starter.yml'? If so, would the "DependsOn" condition help? [Conditions - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cjobs#pipeline-behavior-when-build-is-canceled)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for their answers, I managed to do what I wanted:
In following example:

- There are two pipelines ('Starter' and 'Processing')
- 'Starter' gets input parameters in variables
- 'Starter' triggers 'Processing' (*- template: Processing.yml*) and passes input parameters to it (*parameters: firstName: $(FirsName)*)
- Processing uses the parameters (*${{parameters.firstName}}*)

Starter

```
   trigger: none

   pool:
     vmImage: 'windows-2019'

   stages:
   - stage: A
     jobs:
     - template: Processing.yml
       parameters:
         firstName: $(FirsName)
         lastName: $(LastName)
   
     - job: Finishing
       steps:
        - task: PowerShell@2
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |
              # Write your PowerShell commands here.
       
              Write-Host "Finished"
```

Processing

```
   parameters:
     - name: firstName
       default: ''
     - name: lastName
       default: ''

   jobs:
   - job: Processing
     pool:
       vmImage: 'windows-2019'
     steps:
     - task: PowerShell@2
       inputs:
         targetType: 'inline'
         script: |
           # Write your PowerShell commands here.
    
           Write-Host "Hello  from second pipeline ${{parameters.firstName}}"
```

For using parallel jobs you have to buy microsoft-hosted parallel jobs (settings of your project):
[image]

Comment: Glad to know that you have found the answer. You can accept your answer. This will be helpful to other users who has the same issue.